# Combining several dataframe results with for Loop in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have these functions:

```
def query():
    dict = (
             { "NO" : 1, "PART" : "ALPHA" }, 
             { "NO" : 2, "PART" : "BETA" }
           )
    finalqueryresult = pandas.DataFrame()

    for info in dict: #I use this loop to request query depends on the dict data, in this example twice (2 records from dict)
         finalqueryresult.append( sendquery(info["NO"], info["PART"]) )

def sendquery( no, part):
     *some code to request query to server and save it under reqresult variable*
     *.....*
     *.....*
     return reqresult
```

For example above, when sending first query (record with "NO" = 1) it will return: (lets say this is **df1**)

```
  NAME  COUNTRY
1  RYO   JPN
2  JON   NZ
```

and the last query (record with "NO" = 2): (lets say this **df2**)

```
   NAME    COUNTRY
1  TING      CN
2  ASHYU     INA
```

and what I want is **finalqueryresult** will be like this: (*df1 combined with df2*):

```
  NAME     COUNTRY
1 RYO        JPN
2 JON        NZ
3 TING       CN
4 ASHYU      INA
```

But I failed, the **finalqueryresult** is always empty. I suppose something is wrong with this:

```
for info in dict:
     finalqueryresult.append( sendquery(info["NO"], info["PART"]) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first append all `DataFrames` to list `dfs` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs= []
for info in dict:
     #sendquery(info["NO"], info["PART"] return DataFrame
     dfs.append( sendquery(info["NO"], info["PART"]) )

finalqueryresult = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: nice ! I didn't know about the `ignore_index` argument.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!